# Setting Up SPF Records on Plesk 11

Tags: email, plesk, spf

I see that Plesk 11 automatically sets up an SPF Record - however when I test it on a number of eMail Spam Test services I see that it is not being detected.

```
v=spf1 +a +mx -all
```

What changes do I need to make to this TXT SPF record for it to function correctly?

[image: DNS Records]

Answer (score 1):

**Wrong Nameservers?**

If the domain in your image is the one that is having the issue, the nameservers are set to:

```
nserver:      ns1.blacknight.com  
nserver:      ns2.blacknight.com
```

Based on the IPs of these nameservers, I doubt they are hosted on your Plesk server.

If I query your Plesk server directly, I get the expected result.

```
 dig +short @docklandsstudios.ie docklandsstudios.ie txt
 "v=spf1 +a +mx -all"
```

To correct this you can either:

Update ns1.blacknight.com with the appropriate `TXT` records.

or

Update your domain to use your Plesk server as the authoritative nameservers.

**SPF, Plesk & Qmail**

Plesk supports both Qmail and Postfix.

If you are using Qmail, your default `TXT` records for `SPF` likely will be incorrect if a site has a dedicated IP address.

With Qmail, all email is sent from the server's primary IP address (e.g. eth0) -- regardless of the IP assigned to the site.

As a result, the default record:

`v=spf1 +a +mx -all`

does not include the primary IP address for any site on a different IP.

To correct this, I recommend adding:

`v=spf1 ip4:PRIMARYIP +a +mx -all`

where "PRIMARYIP" is the primary IP address of the server.

With Postfix this is not an issue since it will route email from the site's dedicated IP address.

In general, I recommend using `ip4:` as it eliminates the need for an additional DNS lookup at the destination server.